# CMake compiler identification unknown under Windows 7 64 bits only without admin rights

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cmake

I am using CMake 2.8.10 and 2.8.11.2 under a Windows 7 64 bits machine.
CMake was installed with an administrator rights account.
I also use Visual Studio 2008 Professional.
My account has not the administrator rights.
CMake works perfectly when I launch CMake with the generator "Visual Studio 9 2008".
It does not work when I launch CMake with the generator "Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64".
I get the following error : "The CXX compiler identification is unknown" and "The C compiler identification is unknown"

What is strange is that if I login with an administrator account, CMake works perfectly with the 2 generators above.

How can I make CMake work with the generator "Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64" in the case I do not have administrator rights ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that Dan Macumber. This was solved by installing the 64 bits components of visual studio 2008. Check if the 64 bits components of visual studio are installed with your visual studio “dvd”/”iso image”/etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: In my configuration, the 64 bits component is already installed